# What is the full command for gdal_calc in ipython?

Tags: ipython, tiff, raster, gdal

I've been trying to use raster calculation in ipython for a tif file I have uploaded, but I'm unable to find the whole code for the function. I keep  finding examples such as below, but am unsure how to use this.

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>0)" --NoDataValue=0
```

I then tried another process by assigning sections, however this still doesn't work (code below)

```
a = '/iPythonData/cstone/prec_7.tif'
outfile = '/iPythonData/cstone/prec_result.tif'
expr = 'A<125'
gdal_calc.py -A=a --outfile=outfile --calc='expr' --NoDataValue=0
```

It keeps coming up with *can't assign to operator*. Can someone please help with the whole code.

Comment: The line that starts `gdal_calc.py` is intended to be run at a command line, not inside Python. You can run a system command from IPython by prefixing it with `!`. Alternatively, you may be able to import the module and use functions inside it from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for `gdal_calc.py`, the file is only about 300 lines. Here is a link to that file.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py

The punchline is that they just create an `OptionParser` object in main and pass it to the `doit()` method (Line 63).  You could generate the same `OptionParser` instance based on the same arguments you pass to it via the command-line and call their `doit` method directly.

That said, a system call is perfectly valid per @thomas-k.  This is only if you really want to stay in the Python environment.